# A conditional active record query

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have a conditional active record query that checks to see if a relationship of type X exists (`.count > 0`) where `attribute x` and `attribute y` match specific input *or* if they match when `attribute x` and `attribute y` are switched.

I currently use an `||` operator with two long active record queries to cover both situations.

```
def coach_of?(user)
  if UserRelation.where(relation_type: 'coach-student').where(user_id: self.id).where(with_user_id: user.id).count > 0 || 
     UserRelation.where(relation_type: 'coach-student').where(user_id: user.id).where(with_user_id: self.id).count > 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Is there a more clever way to do this or is this kind of query acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- `if boolean then true else false end` -> `boolean`.
- `UserRelation.where(user_id: self.id).where(with_user_id: user.id)` -> `UserRelation.where(user_id: self.id, with_user_id: user.id)`
- `active_record_collection.count > 0` -> `active_record_collection.exists?`
- I don't understand why you have to check both ways, a "coach - student" relationship looks unidirectional.

Anyway, if you set up the `coach_students` association, you may write something like this:

```
def coach_of?(user)
  coach_students.where(with_user_id: user).exists? || 
    user.coach_students.where(with_user_id: self).exists?
end
```